# How to sandbox arbitrary, user-submitted Javascript code that draws on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, iframe, eval, sandbox

I'm trying to build an app where users can write custom Javascript code in order to draw graphics on a canvas. I want users to be able to share this code with others and for them to safely run other people's contributed drawing functions in their browser.

What I'm looking for is basically a Javascript sandbox that prevents any major security vulnerabilities. I also want to be able to do the heavy drawing logic in a Web Worker so as to not block the main thread and keep the UI responsive.

So far, I have come up with a minimal implementation, using iframes, multiple domains, and web workers, that looks as follows:

1. The user draws on a canvas that lives on the page (which is retrieved from, say, www.drawing.com).
2. When mouse events occur on the canvas (e.g. the user clicks on it), a postMessage() is performed to an iframe from a different origin (www.drawing-scripts.com). The postMessage provides the code that should be run (as a string), along with a bunch of custom library functions (e.g. circle(), line()) and some additional parameters to be used for drawing (e.g. stroke thickness). Here, the use of a different origin prevents any code eval'ed in the iframe from accessing cookies stored from the main origin (e.g. authentication-related). The iframe is sandboxed using the `sandbox` attribute and the `allow-scripts` attribute to allow it to run JS code.
3. The iframe receives the code and library as strings, and does a postMessage() to a web worker that it spawned upon load. This is done to avoid blocking the main browser thread and blocking the UI rendering during (potentially) high-overhead drawing operations.
4. The web worker, upon load and before any code has been sent to it, uses a whitelist to delete all other functions, as done in the [Node-SO-bot](https://github.com/AmaanC/Node-SO-Bot/blob/21cf2ba826f2db35261b79ea93136feab2c0ae05/source/codeWorker.js).
5. The web worker then receives the message with the code and library as strings from the iframe, and evals the custom code.
6. The library functions that I provide (e.g. `circle()`, and `line()`) simply append the drawing information to a list. This is returned from the web worker back to the iframe via a `postMessage()`, and then is returned back to the main page via another `postMessage()`. Finally, the main page simply performs the drawing operations in the list one-by-one on the canvas.

So the flow basically looks like

mouseClick --> postMessage code to iframe --> postMessage code to whitelisted web worker --> eval() code which appends drawing operations to a list --> return list of drawing ops to iframe --> return list of drawing ops to main page --> perform operations as requested.

This currently works, but has some issues:

- There is a really long round-trip per operation, which slows things down quite a bit. There's a lot of data being passed around before the actual drawing occurs making things visibly slow.
- It's difficult to maintain state across different code snippets. Consider where I have one code snippet that runs a setup() function that pre-computes some data and then draws circles when the user interacts with the canvas, while another pre-computes something else and draws triangles instead, and I want the user to be able to switch between them. I would like each snippet to have the illusion of being able to use the global scope, but it's not clear how to do this.
- If an error occurs in the eval'ed code, it's difficult to figure out the line number, although this just seems to be an issue with eval() in general.
- Finally, it's not clear how secure this scheme is and if there are any holes in the flow.
- Is there a way to simplify this? I've seen that sandbox sites use iframes this way to sandbox code, but I have the additional complexity of wanting to draw onto a canvas using multiple code snippets. Has this been done somewhere already?

Comment: Take a look at how Stack Snippet and jsfiddle work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all this.

According to your point *2.* your users are not passing "arbitrary" code that has to be executed.
What they are sending is just data that your app produced, coordinates, colors, maybe text or what else that your app will process.

#### You absolutely don't need `eval`.

What you need is a way to stringify your app's commands, and then to parse it.

For instance, if your user draws a line from 10, 10 to 15,15, you could store something like

```
{ type: "line", x1: 10, y1: 10, x2: 15, y2: 15 }
```

or even SVG like `M10,10L15,15`.

Then when you retrieve the user's data, you simply parse it and call **your** drawing commands that do match.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

inp.oninput = e => parseAndDraw(inp.value);
const availableCommands = {
  clear({x=0, y=0, w=canvas.width, h=canvas.height}) {
    ctx.clearRect(x, y, w, h);
  },
  beginPath(cmd) {
    ctx.beginPath();
  },
  line({x1, y1, x2, y2}) {
    if(!isNaN(x1))
      ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
  },
  stroke({color = "black", lineWidth = 1}) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

inp.oninput();

function parseAndDraw(str) {
  // a few checks
  try {
    commands = JSON.parse(str);
  }
  catch(e) {
    return wrongData("invalid JSON format");
  }
  if(!Array.isArray(commands)) {
    return wrongData("must be an Array of commands");
  }
  if(
    commands.some(command => !command || typeof command.type !== 'string')
    ) {
    return wrongData("all commands must have a type");
  }
  commands.forEach(draw);
  console.clear();
}

function draw(command) {
  const known_command = availableCommands[command.type];
  if(typeof known_command !== 'function') {
    return wrongData("unknown command");
  }
  known_command(command);
}
function wrongData(reason) {
  console.clear();
  console.error('[wrong data]:', reason);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid; }
#inp { width: 100%; height: 100vh; background: ivory }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas><br>
<textarea id="inp" row="15">
[
  {
    "type": "clear",
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "w": 300,
    "h": 150
  },  
  {
    "type": "beginPath"
  },
  {
    "type": "line", 
    "x1": 10,
    "y1": 10,
    "x2": 35,
    "y2": 35.5
  },  
  {
    "type": "line",
    "x2": 80,
    "y2": 35.5
  },
  {
    "type": "line",
    "x2": 50,
    "y2": 70
  },
  {
    "type": "stroke",
    "color": "red",
    "lineWidth": 1
  }
]
</textarea>
```

There is no reason for this to be less safe than using your app in the first place.

And remember that the 2D canvas API has a [Path2d](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/) interface which can greatly ease building complex paths using SVG syntax:

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const user_input = "M10,10L35,35.5L80,35.53L50,70";
const path = new Path2D(user_input);
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.stroke(path);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

One thing that might be a bit harder is if you allow your users to interact with ImageData. But while harder, you may also very well use only a set of allowed arithmetic operations to perform on these Objects.

The only one part where there might be a really small security breach (actually more privacy breach), would be if you do allow your users to draw outsourced images, then they would be able to know who's accessed that image, but that's something any website that does display outsourced images has to deal with, and there is no easy solution.

Of course, Zero-Risk is a myth, but while it's possible some browser does spit their user's credit-card numbers all over the web when passing "gimme-the-code" as input to JSON.parse, you'll not be the one to blame.